# Feather Icon not working in Bootstrap Modal

Tags: bootstrap-4, icons, feathericons

- Version: feather-icons@4.29.0, Bootstrap v4.3.1
- using C# RazorPage, asp.net

I am currently trying to build an asp.net web app.  The feather icons work fine on normal pages, but it doesn't show when it is included in a Modal.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="~/lib/layout/feather-icon.css" />

<div class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <i data-feather="pause-circle" class="align-middle"></i>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-12">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary m-1" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
@section Scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/feather-icons/feather.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/lib/feather-icons/feather.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        feather.replace();
    </script>
    <script>
        $(function () {
            $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip()
        });
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="~/js/common/chatting.js"></script>
}
```

As you can see from the below image from web browser devtools, the  tag is not replaced with svg

**Screenshot**
[image: image description]

anyone know of why it cannot find the data-feather elements in the modal?  And if there is a work around?

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.modal ').on('shown.bs.modal', function () {
    // Call feather.replace() after the modal is shown
    feather.replace();
});
```